# How do I set an image so I can save it in swift 2

Tags: ios, camera, uiimage, swift2

Hi I am writing a camera app where the picture will be saved to the cameraroll when you press the photobutton without displaying it. I am almost done, but I have a problem with a piece of code that should work with swift, but don't work with swift 2.

```
  func didTakePhoto() {
    if let videoConection = stillImageOutput2?.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
        videoConection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput2?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, ErrorType) -> Void in
            if sampleBuffer != nil {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, .RenderingIntentDefault)

                var savedImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

            }
        })
    }
}

@IBAction func takePhotoBtn(sender: UIButton) {
    didTakePhoto()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(savedImage, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

When I try to use the image i just created in the function that saves it, it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: What does "wont be accepted by swift2" _mean_? Your question is meaningless. The line compiles, so what's the problem?

Comment: When I try to use the "imageToBeSaved" in the function that saves the photo, it don't work.

Comment: What does "use" mean? What does "it don't work" mean? What happens exactly? There is _no_ `imageToBeSaved` in your code. Explain! If the code above is not what fails, show the code that _does_ fail. How do you know there's a problem?

Comment: Sorry, the `var savedImage` that I created in  `func didTakePhoto()` gives an error when I try to call it in the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` function. How can I fix it?

Comment: Also, the error is "use of unresolved identifyer `savedImage`"

Comment: Your complaint makes no sense. The `var savedImage` that you created in  `didTakePhoto()` is a local variable. You cannot possibly access it in the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` function elsewhere. Do you understand what a local variable is, and how it differs from a property or a global? If not, read my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_scope_and_lifetime  To make these be the same variable, delete `var` and declare this variable at a higher level.

Comment: Oh, I see. It makes more sense now... Thank you realy much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is structured like this:

```
func didTakePhoto() {
     // ...
     var savedImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)
}
@IBAction func takePhotoBtn(sender: UIButton) {
    didTakePhoto()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(savedImage, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

So `savedImage` is declared locally in, and therefore is entirely confined to, the world of `didTakePhoto()`. In the world of `takePhotoBtn`, no `savedImage` exists — and thus you get a compiler error.

You have two choices. You can declare `savedImage` at a higher level that both methods can see:

```
var savedImage:UIImage!
func didTakePhoto() {
     // ...
     savedImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)
}
@IBAction func takePhotoBtn(sender: UIButton) {
    didTakePhoto()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(savedImage, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Or, you can have `didTakePhoto` *return* `savedImage` as its result:

```
func didTakePhoto() -> UIImage {
     // ...
     let savedImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)
     return savedImage
}
@IBAction func takePhotoBtn(sender: UIButton) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(didTakePhoto(), nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this snippet in my project:

```
func saveImage(image: UIImage) 
   let destinationPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.png")
   UIImagePNGRepresentation(rotateImage(image))!.writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: true)

 }


func rotateImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    print(image.imageOrientation.hashValue )
    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Up ) {

        return image //UIImage(CGImage: image, scale: 0.5, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Up)
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)

    image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))
    let copy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return copy
}
```